# How can I see the error from a Perl system command?

Tags: perl

I am running this piece of perl script:

```
system "bash", "-c",
" some command; exit \${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
and die "has failed"
```

Now if `some command` didn't execute correctly, the script will fail with `has failed` without any more useful info.

How do I make the `die` command to print whatever error message that `some command` has produced?

Comment: Have you tried "or die .." instead of "and die .." ?  Note that 'system' doesn't capture the output from the command.  You may want to read up on 'IPC::System::Simple' in CPAN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
system($cmd) == 0 or die "$0: [$cmd] failed: $?\n";
```

See also [Perl Error Variables](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables).

Comment: Note that system returns the exit code from the program you ran. If that program returns 0 to indicate success, which is the Unix convention (but merely a convention), this is fine. Some programs return other non-zero values for success. Some can return one of many values to indicate different sorts of success. You have to know what the particular program does.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that you want to see the result of a command that came before the command that supplies the things that you can inspect. Along with that, the command you are running is `bash`. However, I think you might not need your `exit` command because you can already get that info from one of Perl's error vars.

Here's  program that runs some things through `system` and looks at the various error variables (which you can read more about in [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar)). I also write more about this in [Mastering Perl](https://www.masteringperl.org):

- `$!` is the error from perl trying to execute your command. It's also a "dualvar", which means it has different string and number values.
- `$?` is the status for the closed pipe (which also includes what we think of as the exit value of the command)
- `$^E` is additional OS-specific info, which is interesting in non-unix like environments, including Windows. Otherwise it's the same as `$!`.

Here's a program to try some things with system then inspect the various error variables.

```
#!perl
use v5.26;

my @runs = (
    [ "false" ],
    [ "/etc/hosts" ],
    [ "not_a_command" ],
    [ "bash" , "-c", "not_a_command" ],
    [ "bash" , "-c", "not_a_command; exit 73" ],
    [ "bash" , "-c", "false" ],
    [ "bash" , "-c", "false; exit 37" ],
    );

foreach my $run ( @runs ) {
    my $exit_code = system { $run->[0] } @$run;
    dump_error( $run, $exit_code, $!, $?, $^E );
    }

sub dump_error {
    my( $label, $exit_code, $system_error, $pipe_status, $os_info ) = @_;

    my $system_error_num = $system_error + 0;
    my $system_error_string = $system_error . '';

    my $pipe_binary = sprintf '%016b', $pipe_status;

    my $pipe_exit   = $pipe_status >> 8;
    my $pipe_signal = $pipe_status & 127;
    my $pipe_core   = $pipe_status & 128;

    print <<~"HERE"
    --- @$label ---
        exit:   $exit_code
        system:
          number: $system_error_num
          string: $system_error_string
        pipe:   $pipe_status ($pipe_binary)
          exit:   $pipe_exit
          signal: $pipe_signal
          core:   $pipe_core
        os:     $os_info
    HERE
    }
```

Here's the output, which I'll break up with some comments:

Running just `false` exits with 1. Shift that up 8 bits to get 256. There's no error though: the program did what it was supposed to do"

```
--- false ---
    exit:   256
    system:
      number: 0
      string:
    pipe:   256 (0000000100000000)
      exit:   1
      signal: 0
      core:   0
    os:
```

Trying to run `/etc/hosts`, which is a plain file that is not executable, is an error. The `system` can't start the program at all. Notice that `$!` now has a numeric and string value. Also, the exit code is `-1` which means that `system` could not start the program. Don't worry about that long string of ones, that's just an artifact from `-1` on a 64-bit system:

```
--- /etc/hosts ---
    exit:   -1
    system:
      number: 13
      string: Permission denied
    pipe:   -1 (1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111)
      exit:   72057594037927935
      signal: 127
      core:   128
    os:     Permission denied
```

The next one is almost like the `/etc/hosts`, but this time the file does not exist. Once again `system` can't start the command so it returns `-1`. The value in `$!` has different errors:

```
--- not_a_command ---
    exit:   -1
    system:
      number: 2
      string: No such file or directory
    pipe:   -1 (1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111)
      exit:   72057594037927935
      signal: 127
      core:   128
    os:     No such file or directory
```

Here we get to your problem. This one tries to run a file that does not exist, but this time `system` can run `bash`, so the various error values are a bit different. `$!` ends up the same as the previous try

```
--- bash -c not_a_command ---
    exit:   32512
    system:
      number: 2
      string: No such file or directory
    pipe:   32512 (0111111100000000)
      exit:   127
      signal: 0
      core:   0
    os:     No such file or directory
```

Now extend that one more step to get what you have: a compound command. The first command will fail, but then bash goes on to run the `exit`. That final command is what sets the values in Perl's error values:

```
--- bash -c not_a_command; exit 73 ---
    exit:   18688
    system:
      number: 2
      string: No such file or directory
    pipe:   18688 (0100100100000000)
      exit:   73
      signal: 0
      core:   0
    os:     No such file or directory
--- bash -c false ---
    exit:   256
    system:
      number: 2
      string: No such file or directory
    pipe:   256 (0000000100000000)
      exit:   1
      signal: 0
      core:   0
    os:     No such file or directory
--- bash -c false; exit 37 ---
    exit:   9472
    system:
      number: 2
      string: No such file or directory
    pipe:   9472 (0010010100000000)
      exit:   37
      signal: 0
      core:   0
    os:     No such file or directory
bash: not_a_command: command not found
bash: not_a_command: command not found
```